Shortcut doesn't open deep link to the app it belongs to, but widget does
I have React Native app with deep link support. I've created widget that opens app on specific view:
.widgetUrl(URL(string: "myapp://Dashboard/SpecialView"))
It works alright so i know deep links are working. So after that i created Shortcuts.swift file in my main app and added this:
import AppIntents
import UIKit

@available(iOS 16, *)
struct StartRecordingIntent : AppIntent {
  static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Special"
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
      let url = URL(string: "myapp://Dashboard/SpecialView")
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
      }
        
      return .result()
    }
}

This intent created shortcut "Special" in shortcut list, and when run, should open exactly the same view as the widget. But all im getting is error:
Failed to open URL myapp://Dashboard/SpecialView: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1
"The request to open "com.myapp" failed."
UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000dd7960
{Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=3
"Application com.myapp is neither visible nor entitled, so may not perform un-trusted user actions."

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong and why can't i open app from shortcut exactly like widget does
